# Ruby on Rails model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

New in rails here. I have trouble understanding this specific activerecord association. Can someone help me on this. The model looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :client_occurrences,
           foreign_key: "client_id",
           class_name: "Occurrence"
  has_many :requested_occurrences,
           foreign_key: "requestor_id", 
           class_name: "Occurrence"
end
```

---

And the one it's associated to is:

```
class Occurrence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template, autosave: true
  belongs_to :requestor, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :client, class_name: "User"
end
```

I just can't seem to understand the associations being portrayed here. Everytime I see the user model, I immediately classify it as an issue because here's how I read the association in the user model:

> User has many occurrences alias by client_occurrences and set
>   client_id as foreign_key

It's an issue for me since the foreign_key is not in the proper table (According to my understanding of the code). In addition, client_id and requestor_id are columns found in the Occurrence table.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where your issues are. I would say your reading is correct, namely:

- `User` does have many `Occurence`s (each `Occurence` points back to
  the `User`)
- They are aliased/referenced as `client_occurrences` from
  the perspective of the `User` The `foreign_key` is indeed
  `client_id`.
- That is, the `Occurence` table uses `client_id` to point
  to the `User`

From the point of view of `Occurrence`:

- Each `Occurrence` belongs to a `:client`, which means the field name will be `client_id` (which matches the `foreign_key` clause in the `User` model)
- The item being pointed to is really a `User`

One of the things that's confusing, I think, is that the order of the `has_many` clauses is different from the order of the corresponding `belongs_to` clauses.

Comment: The thing that's making me topsy-turvy is in the User model association. I'm used to the normal association wherein when you declare the "belongs_to" method, that table usually holds the foreign_key

Comment: Yeah.  `has_many` is different.  It's telling the system that the referenced objects will be pointing back to the objects with the `has_many` declaration.

Comment: Oh I get it, correct me If I'm wrong, so what you're saying is that when you declare the foreign_key method in a has_many method, instead of creating a foreign_key in that table, it will tell the system that the defined column is the foreign_key of the associated model?

If that's the case, why can't I just define the foreign_key in the model where the belongs_to method is defined?

Comment: Yes, that's right. As to why Rails requires both declarations, I can only speculate that they didn't want the cross-model dependency.

Comment: You're a life save dude! Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 0):

These are the business rules I gather from that:

```
A User can be associated with an Occurrence as a client

A User can be associated with an Occurrence as a requestor

A User can be associated to many Occurrences

An Occurrence has one requestor User, and one client User
```

The foreign key is specified in the User model because it's associated to the same model multiple times, otherwise rails would default to using "user_id" as the foreign key in the Occurrence model.

Check this link out for the full details on what all the different ActiveRecord Associations do:
 [Rails Guides: ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: I like your name, matches mine. On a serious note, Thank you for the link! I now found that this specific association is called a Self join. It's like a thorn being taken out of my throat.

Comment: scratch that. I'm stupid. It's not self join. But it looks like it :)

Comment: Yea not a self join, just two joins between the same two models. That site is full of well-explained goodies. Mark the answer correct if you liked it!

Comment: This is not a self join.  A self join would be where, say, a user has_many users.